# getting these errors when opening maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Some info:

- I selected `J2EE/Web` developer when installing Eclipse
- I have not installed any other plugin after installing Eclipse.
- I checked marketplace and it seems `m2e` is installed as part of the install configuration I selected.
- When importing the maven project into Eclipse, I get the error below (**see image**).
- When I tried running "mvn clean install" from inside Eclipse (via run maven run configurations), I get an error (**full error text below**)
- On IntelliJ community edition, I have no problem importing the maven project and running "mvn clean install"
- On my terminal, I have no problem running "mvn clean install".

Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks

Eclipse import error
[image: Eclipse import error]

Full Eclipse mvn clean install error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:clean(default) on project cbus-portals-features:Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:clean failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path C:\Users\myuser\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.5.v20221102-0933\jre/../lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: Have you configured a JDK on the Installed JREs preference page?

Comment: Eclipse compiles incrementally, which means that Java files are compiled on save, so the application is ready to be launched/debugged anytime without being built first. Your `pom.xml` tells about things that might need to be done when compiling as well, e.g. compiling Groovy code. The dialog ask you how to handle these things. cobertura-maven-plugin 2.7 has been released 2015 and seems not to work with Java 17 not having a `lib/tools.jar` file like Java 8 does. On your terminal your probably run Maven with Java 8 or lower. So, in Eclipse, in the Maven launch configuration, choose also Java 8.

Comment: @howlger I changed the 'installed JRE" in eclipse config to use java8. In the maven build (run configurations), I can see "runtime JRE" tab is using java8.

Comment: So please edit your question with the new information. Please be aware that running a Maven build from within Eclipse and the Maven plugin connectors which are used to make incrementally compiling work are different things.